# Securing a spring boot REST api

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a beginner in spring boot api . Currently I am through the videos and practicing the programming.
I am developing the application locally using intellij and ultimately aim to deploy to either Google cloud or AWS.

If I want to secure the api using oauth2 then is there any additional cost I need to consider like for eg., authorization server . What all I need to consider like cost, server, platform to deploy etc roughly before I start implementing REST api?any examples to guide for a beginner?

Comment: Follow these guides in order to start with spring security https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ and 
https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth

Comment: this is very opinion based

Answer (score 2):

To secure your REST API, we will have to do the following things:

1- Configure Spring Security and the database.

2- Configure the authorization server and resource server.(you need to Create an Authorization Server)

3- Get an access token and a refresh token.

4- Get a protected Resource (REST API) using an access token.